# camel-restdsl-swagger xml generation can't find required method allowableValues(String)

Tags: apache-camel, swagger-2.0

I am trying to generate XML DSL from Swagger document (OAS2) using camel-restdsl-swagger Maven plugin.
Unfortunately, I am getting

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
      org.apache.camel.model.rest.
        RestOperationParamDefinition.allowableValues(java.lang.String
```

I was using Camel 2.17, bumped version to 2.23 and I see that this method is indeed available in class `RestOperationParamDefinition` for 2.23.

```
 public RestOperationParamDefinition allowableValues(String... allowableValues) {
        this.setAllowableValues(Arrays.asList(allowableValues));
        return this;
    }
```

I encounter no issues while generating Java DSL though.

Another question to authors, if any of them see this post (particularly Claus Ibsen) if they plan to include support of OAS3?

Comment: Can you double check that you are using the same Camel version for all the JARs on your classpath, and also the same Camel version for the camel-restdsl-swagger maven plugin. As this sounds like you are using mixed versions.

Comment: Yes, I am using the same version for all Camel JARs and plugin - currently 2.22.1.I am able to generate XML DSL only if I remove enum declarations from the swagger document.

Comment: Ah okay lets take a look at that, are you able to either create a project on github with your failing example, or to put a .zip file together and create a new JIRA ticket at Apache Camel and upload the .zip file.

Comment: Sure, will do that. Thank you very much, Claus.

Comment: I created sample project with Camel version baseline 2.23 which contains two swagger 2.0 documents, one without enums (successfully generates blueprint xml) and the other failing due to enums. Please advise how can I share it with you privately (I pushed code to bitbucket private repository).

Comment: Does it have to be a private project? Can you not make it generic sample and publish somewhere like on github or bitbucket? We do all our work upstream in the public. For private help then I often only do that for my commercial customers.

Comment: I understand, your feedback is valid. I will modify the sample and provide public access.

Comment: I uploaded project to https://github.com/fg78nc/camel-swagger-rest-generate

Comment: Thanks I logged a ticket to not forget about this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13171

Comment: Thank you. Is OAS3 specification support in the pipeline?

Comment: There is a JIRA ticket but its not started development. We currently focus on Camel 3 development.

Comment: The uploaded project is empty, can you make sure to upload a fully working example, and it would be good with a readme file that tells a bit how to run the example and where the problem is.

Comment: Okay running the generator with `mvn camel-restdsl-swagger:generate` works for me.

Comment: I added documentation describing both successful and error scenarios. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this and providing the example on github. We were able to reproduce the issue and logged a bug ticket (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13171) which will fix the bug in the upcoming releases.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to contribute to the development of this plugin, particularly to OAS3 support.

Comment: Thanks, we have a JIRA ticket about spec 3 support: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12619